# Python save data in variable

Tags: python

this script get data from CSV file and then finds the correct mac address, and then prints the wifi channel.

```py
bssid = "AB:CD:CC:AA:33:AA"
wifichannel = []

file = open("file-01.csv")
next(file)
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader, None)

for row in reader:
  if row:
    if row[header.index("BSSID")] == bssid:
      print(row[header.index(" channel")])
```

Now my question is, how do I make it so it saves the channel output in the "wifichannel" variable so I can later do things like

```py
print(wifichannel)
```

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Jack A, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

```py
if row[header.index("BSSID")] == bssid:
    wifichannel.append(row[header.index(" channel")])
```

will *add* the item to the wifichannel list rather than just print the item - thus collecting your results into a single variable for later.